# How can I use an instance variable with a static recursive method in java? (cumulative sum problem)

Tags: java, recursion, static, static-methods, cumulative-sum

I'm writing some code to figure out the cumulative sum between two numbers recursively, but the method i wrote requires updating a would-be instance variable called "ans".

Since the problem I'm looking at requires the method header to be "public static int sumBetween(int a, int b)", I'm having issues using a non-static variable for this method.

Currently, I have the variable ans set to static but this can of course only run once, and if I call the method afterwards it starts with the variable ans being the last answer, not 0.

I'm new to recursion so I though I would start with some of these problems. Thank you!

Code:

```
/* EXERCISE 2: Cumulative sum
 * 
 * public static int sumBetween(int a, int b)
 * The goal is to find the sum of the values from  to . In math, we would write this problem as ∑=
 */
 static int ans =0;
 
 public static int sumBetween(int a, int b) {
     // base case
     if (a==b) {
         ans = ans +b;
         return ans;
     }
     // recursion
     ans = ans + a + b;
     return sumBetween(a+1, b-1);
 }
```

Comment: Why even use a field if your class does not have state? Make ans a local variable, local to the method and not a static field of the class, since it serves no purpose as a field. A solution will not need that field.

Comment: Rather you would include the value in your return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answer a second ago but deleted their answer - regardless, thank you stranger because it worked:

```
 public static int sumBetween(int a, int b) {
     return sumBetweenHelper(a, b, 0);
 }
 
 public static int sumBetweenHelper(int a, int b, int ans) {
     // base case
     if (a==b) {
         ans = ans +b;
         return ans;
     }
     // recursion
     ans = ans + a + b;
     return sumBetweenHelper(a+1, b-1, ans);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use recursion, the goal can be achieved in O(1) complexity using maths

```
Sum of the number between a and b  
- Step 1 find sum from 1 to a i.e. (a*(a+1))/2 
- Step 2 find sum from 1 to b i.e. (b*(b+1))/2 
- Step 3 Subtract out the result of step 2 by step 1 and add a
```

```
ans = (b*(b+1)/2) - (a*(a+1)/2) + a
```

Comment: thank you! i will look into math to solve this more efficiently as well. i just happened to be asked to solve this using recursion to practice :D